# How to cancel Files.copy() in Java?

Tags: java, io, nio

I'm using Java NIO to copy something:

```
Files.copy(source, target);
```

But I want to give users the ability to cancel this (e.g. if the file is too big and it's taking a while).

How should I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the option `ExtendedCopyOption.INTERRUPTIBLE`.

**Note:**
This class may not be publicly available in all environments.

Basically, you call `Files.copy(...)` in a new thread, and then interrupt that thread with `Thread.interrupt()`:

```
Thread worker = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Files.copy(source, target, ExtendedCopyOption.INTERRUPTIBLE);
    }
}
worker.start();
```

and then to cancel:

```
worker.interrupt();
```

Notice that this will raise a `FileSystemException`.

Comment: In Java SE 8, this option is not supported in the Oracle JDK. Alternatively, consider [using a `FileChannel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42183069/3453226).

Answer (score 1):

For Java 8 (and any java without `ExtendedCopyOption.INTERRUPTIBLE`), this will do the trick:

```
public static void streamToFile(InputStream stream, Path file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try (OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(file))) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        while (true) {
            int len = stream.read(buffer);
            if (len == -1)
                break;

            out.write(buffer, 0, len);

            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                throw new InterruptedException("streamToFile canceled");
        }
    }
}
```