# How to cancel Files.copy() in Java while not using a non api class?

Tags: java, io, nio

I'm downloading an file with `Files.copy` method:

```
Files.copy(in, Paths.get(targetZipFile), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

If the download is slow i wish to cancel it.

I found the following topic on stackoverflow with the same title:
[How to cancel Files.copy() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083896/how-to-cancel-files-copy-in-java)

But this solution uses a private api:

**Access restriction:** The type `'ExtendedCopyOption'` is not API (restriction on required library '`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib\rt.jar'`)

Is there another way to cancel `Files.copy()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to stick with NIO, you can use:

```
try (FileChannel zip = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(targetZipFile),
    StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {

    zip.transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(in), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

As per the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-long-long-), FileChannel.transferFrom will throw a ClosedByInterruptException if the thread is interrupted.