# Force stop Java Files.copy() running on external thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, file-io, nio

The answer here seemed to be a valid solution before Java 8:
[How to cancel Files.copy() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17083896)

But now it doesn't work, because `ExtendedCopyOption.INTERRUPTIBLE` is private.

---

Basically, I need to download a file from some given `URL` and save it to my local file-system using `Files.copy()`.
Currently, I am using a JavaFX Service because I need to show the progress in a `ProgressBar`.

However, I don't know how to block the thread running `Files.copy()` if the operation takes too long.
Using `Thread.stop()` is at least not wanted. Even `Thread.interrupt()` fails.

I also want the operation to terminate gracefully if the internet connection becomes unavailable.

To test the case when no internet connection is available, I'm removing my ethernet cable and putting it back after 3 seconds.
Unfortunately, `Files.copy()` returns only when I put back the ethernet cable, while I would like it to fail immediately.

As I can see, internally `Files.copy()` is running a loop, which prevents the thread from exiting.

---

`Tester`(Downloading OBS Studio exe):

```
/**
 * @author GOXR3PLUS
 *
 */
public class TestDownloader extends Application {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // Block From exiting
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    // Try to download the File from URL
    new DownloadService().startDownload(
        "https://github.com/jp9000/obs-studio/releases/download/17.0.2/OBS-Studio-17.0.2-Small-Installer.exe",
        System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "OBS-Studio-17.0.2-Small-Installer.exe");

    }

}
```

`DownloadService`:

**Using @sillyfly** comment with `FileChannel` and removing `File.copy` seems to work only with calling `Thread.interrupt()` but it is not exiting when the internet is not available..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

/**
 * JavaFX Service which is Capable of Downloading Files from the Internet to the
 * LocalHost
 * 
 * @author GOXR3PLUS
 *
 */
public class DownloadService extends Service<Boolean> {

    // -----
    private long totalBytes;
    private boolean succeeded = false;
    private volatile boolean stopThread;

    // CopyThread
    private Thread copyThread = null;

    // ----
    private String urlString;
    private String destination;

    /**
     * The logger of the class
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DownloadService.class.getName());

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public DownloadService() {
    setOnFailed(f -> System.out.println("Failed with value: " + super.getValue()+" , Copy Thread is Alive? "+copyThread.isAlive()));
    setOnSucceeded(s -> System.out.println("Succeeded with value: " + super.getValue()+" , Copy Thread is Alive? "+copyThread.isAlive()));
    setOnCancelled(c -> System.out.println("Succeeded with value: " + super.getValue()+" , Copy Thread is Alive? "+copyThread.isAlive()));
    }

    /**
     * Start the Download Service
     * 
     * @param urlString
     *            The source File URL
     * @param destination
     *            The destination File
     */
    public void startDownload(String urlString, String destination) {
    if (!super.isRunning()) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
        this.destination = destination;
        totalBytes = 0;
        restart();
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Boolean> createTask() {
    return new Task<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {

        // Succeeded boolean
        succeeded = true;

        // URL and LocalFile
        URL urlFile = new URL(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(urlString, "UTF-8"));
        File destinationFile = new File(destination);

        try {
            // Open the connection and get totalBytes
            URLConnection connection = urlFile.openConnection();
            totalBytes = Long.parseLong(connection.getHeaderField("Content-Length"));





            // --------------------- Copy the File to External Thread-----------
            copyThread = new Thread(() -> {

            // Start File Copy
            try (FileChannel zip = FileChannel.open(destinationFile.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {

                zip.transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream()), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);


                // Files.copy(dl.openStream(), fl.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                stopThread = true;
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "DownloadService failed", ex);
            }

            System.out.println("Copy Thread exited...");
            });
            // Set to Daemon
            copyThread.setDaemon(true);
            // Start the Thread
            copyThread.start();
            // -------------------- End of Copy the File to External Thread-------






            // ---------------------------Check the %100 Progress--------------------
            long outPutFileLength;
            long previousLength = 0;
            int failCounter = 0;
            // While Loop
            while ((outPutFileLength = destinationFile.length()) < totalBytes && !stopThread) {

            // Check the previous length
            if (previousLength != outPutFileLength) {
                previousLength = outPutFileLength;
                failCounter = 0;
            } else
                ++failCounter;

            // 2 Seconds passed without response
            if (failCounter == 40 || stopThread)
                break;

            // Update Progress
            super.updateProgress((outPutFileLength * 100) / totalBytes, 100);
            System.out.println("Current Bytes:" + outPutFileLength + " ,|, TotalBytes:" + totalBytes
                + " ,|, Current Progress: " + (outPutFileLength * 100) / totalBytes + " %");

            // Sleep
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "", ex);
            }
            }

            // 2 Seconds passed without response
            if (failCounter == 40)
            succeeded = false;
           // --------------------------End of Check the %100 Progress--------------------

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            succeeded = false;
            // Stop the External Thread which is updating the %100
            // progress
            stopThread = true;
            LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "DownloadService failed", ex);
        }







        //----------------------Finally------------------------------

        System.out.println("Trying to interrupt[shoot with an assault rifle] the copy Thread");

        // ---FORCE STOP COPY FILES
        if (copyThread != null && copyThread.isAlive()) {
            copyThread.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Done an interrupt to the copy Thread");

            // Run a Looping checking if the copyThread has stopped...
            while (copyThread.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("Copy Thread is still Alive,refusing to die.");
            Thread.sleep(50);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Download Service exited:[Value=" + succeeded + "] Copy Thread is Alive? "
            + (copyThread == null ? "" : copyThread.isAlive()));

        //---------------------- End of Finally------------------------------




        return succeeded;
        }

    };
    }

}
```

Interesting questions:

1-> [What does java.lang.Thread.interrupt() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590000/what-does-java-lang-thread-interrupt-do)

Comment: If a thread doesn't end up in a loop, it will stop automatically. Now if the thread does keep running it means it's in a loop and you seem to want to use `Thread.interrupt()` to stop it. But this can only work if there is any interruption within the thread, for example `Thread.pause(x)`. Otherwise the JVM doesn't know when to interrupt the thread, it wouldn't be healthy if it did in the middle of a file writing operation.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like you'll have to use something like a [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), similar to what's described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35875142/how-to-cancel-files-copy-in-java-while-not-using-a-non-api-class/35877509).  This does seem like overkill though, so perhaps there is a simpler way.

Comment: @sillyfly I think your option will do perfectly and for the connection loss testing a timeout could be used, somewhat like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529733/how-to-use-urlconnection-timeout).

Comment: I noticed that you didn't accept any answer yet, please consider doing that at some point.

Comment: @GhostCat No answer is completely correct my friend.

Answer (score 11):

I strongly encourage you to use a [`FileChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html).
It has the [`transferFrom()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferFrom-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-long-long-) method which returns immediately when the thread running it is interrupted.
(The Javadoc here says that it should raise a `ClosedByInterruptException`, but it doesn't.)

```
try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(...), StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                            StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
    channel.transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(new URL(...).openStream()), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

It also has the potential to perform much better than its `java.io` alternative.
(However, it turns out that the implementation of `Files.copy()` may elect to delegate to this method instead of actually performing the copy by itself.)

---

Here's an example of a reusable JavaFX Service that lets you fetch a resource from the internet and save it to your local file-system, with automatic graceful termination if the operation takes too long.

- The service task (spawned by `createTask()`) is the user of the file-channel API.
- A separate [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is used to handle the time constraint.
- Always stick to the [good practices](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) for extending [`Service`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html).
- If you choose to use such an high-level method, you won't be able to track down the progress of the task.
- If the connection becomes unavailable, `transferFrom()` should eventually return without throwing an exception.

To start the service (may be done from any thread):

```
DownloadService downloadService = new DownloadService();
downloadService.setRemoteResourceLocation(new URL("http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test1Gb.db"));
downloadService.setPathToLocalResource(Paths.get("C:", "test1Gb.db"));
downloadService.start();
```

and then to cancel it (otherwise it will be automatically cancelled after the time expires):

```
downloadService.cancel();
```

Note that the same service can be reused, just be sure to reset it before starting again:

```
downloadService.reset();
```

Here is the `DownloadService` class:

```
public class DownloadService extends Service<Void> {

    private static final long TIME_BUDGET = 2; // In seconds

    private final ScheduledExecutorService watchdogService =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
                private final ThreadFactory delegate = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

                @Override
                public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                    Thread thread = delegate.newThread(r);
                    thread.setDaemon(true);
                    return thread;
                }
            });
    private Future<?> watchdogThread;

    private final ObjectProperty<URL> remoteResourceLocation = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private final ObjectProperty<Path> pathToLocalResource = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public final URL getRemoteResourceLocation() {
        return remoteResourceLocation.get();
    }

    public final void setRemoteResourceLocation(URL remoteResourceLocation) {
        this.remoteResourceLocation.set(remoteResourceLocation);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<URL> remoteResourceLocationProperty() {
        return remoteResourceLocation;
    }

    public final Path getPathToLocalResource() {
        return pathToLocalResource.get();
    }

    public final void setPathToLocalResource(Path pathToLocalResource) {
        this.pathToLocalResource.set(pathToLocalResource);
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Path> pathToLocalResourceProperty() {
        return pathToLocalResource;
    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        final Path pathToLocalResource = getPathToLocalResource();
        final URL remoteResourceLocation = getRemoteResourceLocation();
        if (pathToLocalResource == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("pathToLocalResource property value is null");
        }
        if (remoteResourceLocation == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("remoteResourceLocation property value is null");
        }

        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws IOException {
                try (FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(pathToLocalResource, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                                                            StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
                    channel.transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(remoteResourceLocation.openStream()), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void running() {
        watchdogThread = watchdogService.schedule(() -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> cancel());
        }, TIME_BUDGET, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void succeeded() {
        watchdogThread.cancel(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void cancelled() {
        watchdogThread.cancel(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed() {
        watchdogThread.cancel(false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is one important aspect not covered by the other answers/comments; and that is a wrong assumption of yours:

> What I want is it to fail immediately when no internet connection is there.

It is not that easy. The TCP stack/state machine is actually a pretty complicated thing; and depending on your context (OS type; TCP stack implementation, kernel parameters, ...), there can be situations where a network partition takes place and a sender doesn't notice for 15 or more **minutes**. Listen [here](http://www.se-radio.net/2017/02/se-radio-episode-282-donny-nadolny-on-debugging-distributed-systems/) for more details on that.

In other words: "just pulling the plug" is no way equal to "immediately breaking" your existing TCP connection. And just for the record: you don't need to plug cables manually to simulate network outages. In a reasonable test setup, tools like *iptables* aka firewalls can do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to need an Asynchronous/Cancellable HTTP GET which can be tough.

The problem is that if read stalls waiting for more data (cable is pulled) it won't quit until either the socket dies or new data comes in.

There are a few path you could follow, tinkering with socket factories to set a good timeout, using http client with timeouts and others.

I would have a look at [Apache Http Components](http://hc.apache.org) which has non blocking HTTP based on java NIO Sockets.